# Bootstrap modal hidden event reload the body via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page that popup a modal and using `hidden.bs.modal` event, I want to reload the same page contents i.e `body` tag `html` via ajax. I have the following code:

```
$("#actions-modal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        alert(document.location)
        $.ajax({
            url: document.location,
            type: "get",
            sucess: function(data){
                alert('hhhh')
                return $("#body1").html($(data).find('#body1'));
            },
            error: function(xhr){
                console.log(xhr);
            }
        })
    })
```

In the above code, `alert(document.location)` works fine. However, both `alert('hhhh')` in `success` handler of the ajax and `console.log(xhr)` in the error handler of the ajax **don't work** at all. i.e there is no `success` nor `error`! Additionally, there is no any errors in the browser's console.

Answer (score 0):

`document.location` will return you the object, So try using `document.location.href` which will return you the string of URL. Then the AJAX call will start working.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `return` from your success function. You don't need to return when changing the html of an element. The return is only required when doing something like this:

```
function getHTML() 
{
    $.ajax({
            url: document.location,
            type: "get",
            sucess: function(data){
                return data;
            },
            error: function(xhr){
                return "Failed";
            }
    });
}

var myHTML = getHTML();
$('#body1').html(myHTML);
```

However, when you are immediately setting the html you don't need it.